# grammatical role of leaving

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

What is the grammar and structure of "leaving" in the following sentence?

> In some cases the loose soil is blown completely away, **leaving** a
>   stony surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"leaving" is the head of a participial clause functioning as an adverbial which might denote consequence, as it expresses the result of the blowing away of the loose soil:

- In some cases the loose soil is blown completely away, **thus** leaving a stony surface.
- In some cases the loose soil is blown completely away, leaving **as a result** a stony surface.